# Adding carousel with jQuery-1.9.1.min to Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, carousel

Hi I am trying to add the sky touch jQuery carousel to Magento but whenever I add jquery-1.9.1.min.js a number of JS conflicts occur in the debugging console.(uncaught type error) I am sure it is a conflict between two jQuery library's but how do I fix this.

I have tried to add jQuery no conflict to the call slider code in the head but it still does not work.

Any help will be super apreciated. thanks

These are the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchstart' of undefined jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:10
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' prototype.js:5644
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish' superfish.js:123
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'carousel' of null
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your custom theme (app>design>frontend>default>customtheme>layout), Layout folder open page.xml file

Find

```
 <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

Put your include js code above prototype.js , I have added custom jquery files and it works for me.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>customtheme/jquery.1.8.2.mins.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>customtheme/jquery.bxslider.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>customtheme/highslide.js</script></action>
```

Hope this will works to you!

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but it still is conflicting, but a few less JS errors.

Comment: can you please add "jQuery.noConflict();" in your version jquery file at the end, i know it is not a right way to do it, but it has solved error of mine, try that if you can resolve your errors!

Comment: Ok I tried that.. but problem persists. it seems to be conflicting with